# Paragraph title in ConTeXt (similar to LaTeX \paragraph{})

Tags: sectioning, context, sections-paragraphs

I want to have inline paragraph titles in ConTeXt with a mark and spacing:

*This is my paragraph*  @  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

The `@` above should be a symbol (diamond or bullet) and I need 2em spacing before and after it. Paragraph title style should be smallcaps.

I was attempting to do it with [`\setuphead`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead) without success, as I can not disable the newline after the title. I also don't like inheriting `subsubsubject`. I would prefer to add it one level below `subsubsubject` despite I don't want paragraph titles in the TOC.

```
\definehead[bekezdes][subsubsubject]
\setuphead[bekezdes][
  after=\quad\bullet\quad,
  style=\sc
]
```

The above code produces the following title:

[image]

I would very appreciate a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `alternative=text` to get rid of the newline after the section title. Regarding TOC, can you create a MWE to show how you are invoking the TOC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply set `alternative=text` to get the correct spacing. With `altenative=text`, `before` and `after` keys are ignored. Instead you can use `commandafter` to set the bullet after the section title. By default, ConTeXt inserts a skip of `textdistance` after the section head, so I set it to `0pt`.  Here is the complete example:

```
\definehead[paragraph][subsubsubsection]
\setuphead [paragraph]
           [
             number=no, % To imitate LaTeX
             textdistance=0pt,
             commandafter={\quad\bullet\quad\null},
             alternative=text,
             style=sc,
          ]

\starttext
\startparagraph[title=Knuth quote]
  \input knuth
\stopparagraph
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Note that there is more space after the bullet. Without a fix, Henri's answer does this better. I tried to adjust head and indentation settings to fix this without success yet. Still, I would happily accept this one as it is based on the headings which seems more transparent to me. Not that it only affects `\startparagraph` and not `\paragraph{}`.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam: There appears to be a regular space after the head title (and I couldn't figure out a way to signal that the space should not be inserted). You can get rid of that by using `textdistance=-\currentspaceskip` (I think, I did not measure the resulting output).

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative approach you could define an enumeration.

```
\defineenumeration
  [paragraph]
  [
    text=,
    number=no,
    title=yes,
    titlestyle=sc,
    titledistance=0pt,
    titleleft=,
    titleright={\quad\bullet},
    distance=1em,
    alternative=serried,
  ]

\starttext

\startparagraph{Knuth quote}
  \input knuth
\stopparagraph

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: For the sake of consistency, I prefer to use `\startparagraoh[title=..]` which also works with descriptions and enumerations... and why not use a description environment instead or enumeration?