# How to center \paragraph title?

Tags: paragraphs

I would like to center the title of my `\paragraph` command to have a display like this :
[image]

I tried to use the `\paragraph{\centering paragraph's title}` but it does not work. I am looking for a way to customize the `\paragraph`command without using [ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375922/paragraph-title-in-context-similar-to-latex-paragraph).

Thank you for your help, have a good day.

Comment: @Christian ok so what is the correct name of the `\section` and `\paragraph` objects?

Comment: You should take a look at the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, lipsum}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]{\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0pt}{}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\paragraph{Paragraph title}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this way but it does not work with my document, maybe there is a conflict with another package.

Comment: Could you post a minimal full example that doesn't work this way?

Comment: I found the problem, there must have been a conflict between `sectsty` and `titlesec`: removing `sectsty`from my package list has solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Bernard, I will get deep look at the `titlesec`package.

Comment: Oh yes. They operate on the same kind of objects, and this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you can use *scrartcl* class from koma-script

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% to have paragraph not in run-in format, afterskip has to be postive
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterskip = .5em,
]{paragraph}

%center title
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\centering}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\paragraph{Paragraph title}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: With koma-script]